# Accessing the Spinner's Layout and set its TextView

Tags: android, spinner

I am trying to set the TextView of the Spinner, but I cannot reach it. There are many solutions about this issue but all of them solve from Spinner Adapter. In my issue I must not change the text from Adapter. I want to change it from the spinner object itself.

So I tried several ways to solve it.

1)

```
LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(spnSektorInsert.getContext());
View convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.spinner_item, null);
TextView txtSpinner = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtSpinner);

txtSpinner.setText("Something");
txtSpinner.setTextColor(Color.RED);
```

2)

```
View convertView = spnSektorInsert.getAdapter().getView(0, null, null);
TextView txtSpinner = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtSpinner);

txtSpinner.setText("Something");
txtSpinner.setTextColor(Color.RED);
```

3)

```
TextView txtSpinner = (TextView) spnSektorInsert.getChildAt(0);
txtSpinner.setText("Something");
txtSpinner.setTextColor(Color.RED);
```

In the first two ways, nothing happened, in the last way, the application crashed with NullPointerException. Any ideas will be appreciated.

Comment: To alter the textview of a spinner, you HAVE to use a custom spinner adapter to set it yourself, AFAIK there isn't a way to get around this

Comment: @MattTaylor I already have a custom spinner adapter. Actually, I want to change the text to warn user in case of an inconsistent data. So I didn't want to add this inconsistent data into the list for spinner.

Comment: aaah, I get your problem now, sorry, your question wasn't quite clear. it might be worth rewording your question to reflect this. Although looking at your comment, your question is __completely__ misworded, as you're talking about spinner option validation. Surely you want to validate it when the user enters the data in the first place?

Comment: It is normal that my question wasn't clear because my issue is too specific. It seems I solved my problem by slightly changing the adapter. In my project I am getting data from another company's database, but there is too much my inconsistent data, so my application can crush. Therefore I have to warn users if there is an inconsistent data in some components of the app. So that spinner is one of them.

Comment: Your question being specific is **no** excuse for it also being unclear

Comment: To make the question clear, I had to copy and paste thousands of codes  here, and you would have to read them all which I never expected. My app has lots of customized components and adapters using complicated and sometimes inconsistent data. So it is totally excuse my question being specific. Anyway, the problem already solved.

Comment: @EgemenHamutçu could you post your solution as an answer here, please?